# Extract values from a range with 2 columns only if the value in column 1 contains a specific word in the column 2

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I need to extract each individual person from a list that doesn't contain a certain activity (Project). Sounds easy but I can't quite get to the end of it.

Please check the example here on Sheet 2:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qjbjXFCYj1qXrVVGNnhOj11asxT_o1xHWXerRqAl1UQ/edit#gid=2105763617

[image]

Here's the logic.
First I attempted to see if the individual only occurs once and if the Activity is not "Project"

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(and(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=1,B2<>"Project"),0,1),"")
```

Then I just extract the name that satisfies this criteria:

```
=query(ARRAYFORMULA(iF(I2:I=0,A2:A,"")), "where Col1 <>'' ")
```

This works, except there might be multiple assignments for the same person that does not contain the activity "Project" which my formula doesn't account for nor is it a simple dynamic arrayformula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, B2:B<>"Project"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:B, "select A where B <>'Project'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, B2:B<>"Project", 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, FILTER(A:A, B:B="Project"))&"$"))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I like the first one but not sure why you included the third one as it did not return `George`?

Comment: @TerryW the 3rd one is for case when only unique names are needed that never had Project

Comment: @player0 Thanks, this does the job but I'm attempting to optimize this. The spreadsheet took a huge performance hit when I introduced this formula

Answer (score 0):

While @player0's answer solves the question, it took a big performance hit on a sheet with >1000 rows.
Instead, I extracted all names that contained "Project" and then all names that did not contain "Project", then subtracted all the names from the first array to eliminate names that were in both.

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, B2:B<>"Project")), ISNA(MATCH(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, B2:B<>"Project")), UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, B2:B="Project")),0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this also:*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:A$25,MATCH(0,IF($C$1<>$B$2:$B$25,COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,$A$2:$A$25), ""), 0)),"")}
```

**N.B.**

- Cell `C1` has criteria *Project*, using cell reference makes the formula
  dynamic rather than hard coded.
- Enter this formula in cell F2, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**,
  and fill down.